# Check for Space character in input with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form where a user will set up a new Username. The issue is user's have been creating username's with a space and I want to avoid that.

I have been able to detect when there is a space using the following:

```
var hasSpace = $('#usernameValue').val().indexOf(' ')>=0;
```

However I cannot figure out to have the form check for that space when the user is typing in that input section.

How would I change my code to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try input.onkeyup event. input is your input variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested you can use the keyup function. This example checks if you entered space and alerts the user

```
$('#usernameValue').keyup(function(e) {   
   if (e.which === 32)  {
     alert('you entered space');
     // Do whatever logic is needed here
   }
});
```

[Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xa7z314v/1/)

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! If anyone is curious how to also remove the space check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/hDtA3/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an input tag?

If so, you can use the pattern attribute to define a regular expression that doesn't accept whitespaces. For example:

```
    <input type="text" name="username" pattern="/^\S*$/">
```

For more information: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Using onkeyup event.

```
input.onkeyup = function(){
   var hasSpace = $('#usernameValue').val().indexOf(' ')>=0;
}
```